# How to Add Default Elements to an Array when Requirements Not Met?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code that converts user input to an array then does a fetch request. The rest of the code only works when the array has a quantity (as a string) and a unit (as a string). So for example, it works when I type in "1 whole apple" or "1 oz chicken thigh" but it breaks when it's just "apple". How can I set up a checkpoint to add "1" and "whole" to the beginning of the array when quantity and unit are missing?

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("")

const foodName = []
const searchArray = []


// This part below separates user input by space then forms an array

const inputArray = input.split(/(\s+)/).filter(e => String(e).trim())



// This part below forms a new array with only the quantity and the unit, or nested arrays if the user inputs more than one item, which obviously breaks if there is no quantity. 


const array = inputArray.reduce(
      (arrays, value) => (
        isFinite(value)
          ? arrays.push([value])
          : arrays[arrays.length - 1].push(value),
          arrays
      ),
      []
      )


// This part below combines food name to a single element if it has more than one word i.e. apple pie. 

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      const foodName = array[i].splice(2).join(' ')
      foodArray.push(foodName)
      const wholeArray = array[i].concat(foodArray[i])
      searchArray.push(wholeArray)
    }

Making the fetch request etc.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up adding an error message since I could not find a solution to this.

```
if (!isFinite(inputArray[0])) {
      setErrorMessage('Be sure to specify quantity and unit!')
      return
}

const array = inputArray.reduce(
      (arrays, value) => (
        isFinite(value)
          ? arrays.push([value])
          : arrays[arrays.length - 1].push(value),
          arrays
      ),
      []
    )
```